# Non-normality and Heteroscedasticity in Spatial Data

Tags: spatial-economics

I am working on district-level Spatial Analysis for my project. The OLS, Spatial models show non-normality and heteroscedasticity issues in the estimation. What can I do? Suggest references I can look for. I am using GeoDa software.